# In Emacs Lisp, how to find where the symbol is defined

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I do `C-h f` or `C-h v`, Help tells me in which file the symbol is defined or where it will be autoloaded from. How can I find the same information programmatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some digging reveals that

```
(find-lisp-object-file-name object type)
```

Should do the trick. As an example:

```
(find-lisp-object-file-name 'goto-line 'function)
;; => "/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/simple.el"
```

EDIT: How I discovered this information:

First I did `C-h k C-h f` to figure out what `C-h f` is bound to. The result is `describe-function`, so let's do `C-h f describe-function` to see the source for that. I noticed that it was essentially an interactive wrapper around `describe-function-1`, so I jumped to the source for that. There's a lot of stuff in there, but the pertinent line is:

```
(file-name (find-lisp-object-file-name function def))
```

Revealing that `find-lisp-object-file-name` is the function used to do this work internally.

Comment: `(find-lisp-object-file-name 'goto-line 'function)` returns `nil` for me. `(find-lisp-object-file-name 'goto-line (symbol-function 'goto-line))` returns the filename, as described by @jisang-yoo in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

To add to James Porter's answer

```
;;; run from: emacs -q

(require 'cl) ; for incf

(print (list
        ;; goto-line is a function defined in simple.el
        (find-lisp-object-file-name 'goto-line (symbol-function 'goto-line))
        ;; print is a function defined in C
        (find-lisp-object-file-name 'print (symbol-function 'print))
        ;; rx is an autoload from rx.el
        (find-lisp-object-file-name 'rx (symbol-function 'rx))
        ;; incf is an alias for cl-incf defined in cl.el
        (find-lisp-object-file-name 'incf (symbol-function 'incf))
        ;; cl-incf is defined in cl-lib.el
        (find-lisp-object-file-name 'cl-incf (symbol-function 'cl-incf))))
;; => ("c:/run/Emacs/lisp/simple.el" C-source 
;;  "c:/run/Emacs/lisp/emacs-lisp/rx.el" "c:/run/Emacs/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl.el"
;;  "c:/run/Emacs/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-lib.el")

(print (list
        ;; print-circle is a variable defined in C
        (find-lisp-object-file-name 'print-circle 'defvar)
        ;; indent-line-function is a variable defined in indent.el
        (find-lisp-object-file-name 'indent-line-function 'defvar)))
;; => (C-source "c:/run/Emacs/lisp/indent.el")
```